# when i am using canActivate Guard it's leading to a blank page in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement login functionality with angular 4 but when I am using canActivate Guard its leading me to a blank page,please help me

This is My loginservice

```
 isAuthenticated(){
   return localStorage.getItem('token') != null ;
   }
```

This is canActivate guard

```
  canActivate(route : ActivatedRouteSnapshot , state : RouterStateSnapshot){

    return this.loginservice.isAuthenticated();
  }
```

This is Router Module

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path : '' , redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch :'full' },
  {path : 'login' , component : LoginComponent },
  {path : 'home' , component : HomeComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuard] ,children :[

          {path : 'adduser' , component : AdduserComponent },
          ]
```

Comment: What do you think it should display instead of a blank page, and why? How are you testing this?

Comment: In browser i am passing URL localhost:4200/home

Comment: So, I repeat: what do you think it should display instead of a blank page, and why? You tell angular to display the page for /home. The guard tells angular not to do that because the user is not authenticated (and doesn't tell it anything else). What should angular display then, and why?

Comment: I want it to go back to login page

Comment: because my default router is redirecting to login

Comment: Then tell it to do that. It can't magically guess. In the guard, if the user is not authenticated, navigate to the login page.

Comment: Your default route is redirecting to login, but /home is not your default route.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your AuthGuard should redirect you to a default page if you are not authenticated or unauthorized.

```
constructor( private loginservice: LoginService, private router: Router) {

    }
public canActivate(route : ActivatedRouteSnapshot , state : RouterStateSnapshot){

    if(!this.loginservice.isAuthenticated()) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']); // choose either default route like here
            return false;
        }
    return true;
  }
```